# when uiactionsheet show,click button of uiactionsheet,uiviewcontroller not support rotate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiactionsheet, autorotate

When I use `UIActionSheet` in my view controller, my viewcontroller support four directions，I create a `UIActionSheet`,and show `UIActionSheet`. When I touch a button of `UIActionSheet`, the `UIActionSheet` dismiss, then rotate my iPhone, my view controlle not support rotate. not execute the delegate of rotate,such as:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have to set orientation from build setting... see image for xcode 5.

Comment: thank your answer Pravin,I have set device orientations include three orientations:Portrait,Landscape Left,Landscape Right.

before UIActionSheet show,app can autorotate.After the UIActionSheet Show,app can't autorotate.